# Error "Error parsing DDL" when trying to ALTER TABLE with ENCRYPTION = 'Y' (keyring plugin) in MySQL 5.7.22

Tags: mysql, encryption, alter

I configured my MySQL 5.7.22 instance with

```
early-plugin-load = keyring_file.dll
```

in my.ini, restarted the service (on Windows Server 2016 Standard)
then I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT) ENCRYPTION='Y';
```

Table was created correctly and it looks like the data is really encrypted (by looking into MySQL data folder).
But when I try to ALTER the table (in Workbench) I see this:

[image]

Why do I get this "Error parsing DDL"?

Other statements like INSERT or SELECT works okay on this encrypted table.

Also ALTER on a non-encrypted table works normally.

Comment: Possible that client tool doesn't understand ENCRYPTION keyword. Try to update application.

Comment: No, it is not about the client. The error pops up when I'm doing ALTER on that encrypted table. Sorry my post was not very clear, please read again, I corrected it.

Comment: I just downloaded MySQL Administrator and I did ALTER on an encrypted table, works normally. Quite strange... any ideas why?

Comment: Yes, this is about the client, not the mysql server. The error message is not a standard mysql error. This is confirmed by your last comment because the same statement works with a different client.

Comment: Probably your workbench was designed for an older mysql version, which did not support the table encryption yet.

Comment: I updated MySQL workbench and it works fine. However I wonder why there is still no encryption option during creation / edition of the table.

Comment: You also can run this script with a free express edition [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated MySQL workbench and it works fine now :-)